# why a simple web page's font is blurry on android?

Tags: android, image-processing, png, html

I have a simple html page on mobile, like this:

```
<ul class="ui-list">
    <li class="ui-border-b">
        <div class="ui-list-thumb">
           <span style="background-image:url(http://yoursite.com/test.png)" class=" ui-border"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-list-info">
            <h4>balabala</h4>
            <p>balabala</p>
        </div>
        <button class="icon-sprite ui-btn-end"></button>
    </li>
</ul>
```

when I test this page on my android phone, it maybe look fuzzy of full page, especially the text font area.
**But often situation is: start from fuzzy, then to clear within 1 second.** On my iPhone it looks good.

> when I change the image to .jpg the problem was gone

, I don't know what's wrong with this png image.

Comment: Are you sure it's not the jpg that looks fuzzy? As you may know it's a compressed format that can be displayed even if not fully downloaded (but fuzzy) Example : http://yuiblog.com/blog-archive/assets/4-prog-example.jpg

Comment: @MichaelLaffargue, it's not the image fuzzy, but full page's fonts looks fuzzy